# PHP 3 to PHP 5 Upgrade... Variables in 3 didn't have $ in front... is there a setting for back compat?

Tags: php, variables

OK, this is an odd request, and it might not even be fully true... but I'm upgrading someone's system ... and they are using OSCommerce (from a long time ago).

It appears their variables are referrenced without a dollar sign in front of them (which is new to me). I haven't done PHP in about 7 years, and I've always used dollar signs.

Is there a setting that I can throw in PHP 5 that says to assume these are variables?

Example:

```
mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_UserName, DB_Password);
```

in my day, that would be:

```
mysql_connect($DB_Server, etc, etc);
```

Their site has THOUSANDS of files... no I don't want to go put dollar signs in front of everything.

HELP!

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe OSCommerce actually DEFINES these values, so the usage is correct (without the $).

Look for

```
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
```

or something similar.

In other words, do *not* go through and update these with a $ before if they're actually defined constants.

Comment: Yeah, I just re-tested... and "echo DB_SERVER;" worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [constants](http://www.php.net/constant).

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly a big difference is the lack of 'register_globals' being default to 'ON'. You might need to change a lot of instances here $var should be $_REQUEST['var'] or the appropriate $_GET/$_POST super globals.

And as far as constants are concerned you should access them as such:

```
constant('MY_CONSTANT')
```

This avoids PHP assuming that MY_CONSTANT is a string if the constant is not defined.